# Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on test to execute command { createUser:

Tags: mongodb

I'm starting with MongoDB and I would like to user/pass access to the dbs.
The first thing I did was to create and admin user and start mongodb with auth activate, this is my created user:

```
db.getUser("admin") 
{
        "_id" : "admin.admin",
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "clusterAdmin",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ] }
}
```

After that, I try to create users with the following commands:

```
use newdb
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "newuser",
    pwd: "12345678",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "newdb" } ]
  }
)
```

But I got this error:

> Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on newdb to execute command {
>   createUser: "newuser", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db:
>   "newdb" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority",
>   wtimeout: 30000.0 } } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004

I have googled about it but there are only two results, one on Chinese and the other not related, so I'm a little lost. Any idea ? It looks like my admin user doesn't have privilege, I access to the mongodb with the following command:

```
$mongo --port 27017 -u adminUser -p adminPass  --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't include the `userAdmin`/`userAdminAnyDatabase` role in the admin user. `dbAdminAnyDatabase` and `clusterAdmin` don't include user management privileges.

Comment: That was the problem. Well, that was my first encounter with mongodb :) Thank you very much!

Comment: For me "use admin" command helped as I didn't select the db at first

Comment: Login with admin "mongo -u admin" to be able to perform administrator tasks

Answer (score 26):

Stop the running instance of mongod 
`mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --auth`

then start without `--auth` like 
`mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

then update your roles [like](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.updateUser/#db.updateUser)

> db.updateUser("admin",{roles :
>   ["userAdminAnyDatabase","userAdmin","readWrite","dbAdmin","clusterAdmin","readWriteAnyDatabase","dbAdminAnyDatabase"]});

Now again start mongod with `--auth` and try.

---

The idea is you have to create user under "admin" database with all the ROLES mentioned above.

But this user is not part of other databases. So once you created the admin user,

then login as that admin user,

> SERVER:  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --auth
>
> CLIENT:  ./mongodb/bin/mongo localhost:27017/admin -u adminUser -p
>   123456

```
use APPLICATION_DB
```

again create a new user (say APP_USER) for this  APPLICATION_DB. This time for this application user you need only "dbOwner" role.

```
db.createUser({user:"test", pwd:"test", roles:['dbOwner']})
```

Now your application has to use this APP_USER and APP_DB.

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I'm pretty sure you don't need the ';' at the end of the db.updateUser.

Answer (score 22):

I fixed the same problem just exit and login as admin

```
mongo -u admin
```

> enter your admin user password
>
> after login, create a user as usual you mentioned

```
use newdb
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "newuser",
    pwd: "12345678",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "newdb" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: How do I know my admin user and password ?

Comment: for bitnami mongodb, user have to go to system log of ec2 instance to find user and password as mentioned here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro In the Question its mentioned, Admin Account Created First.

Answer (score 8):

in my case:

1.stop mongodb :

```
$ service mongod stop
```

2.editing this /etc/mongod.conf:

```
   security:

     authorization: "disabled"
```

3.then I start again service:

```
$ service mongod start
```

4.Add user:

```
 $ mongo mongodb://localhost:27017
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

5.comment lines from /etc/mongod.conf added in step 2

6.restart mongod

```
 service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 5):

You should exit the current mongod process and restart it again without parameter `--auth`.

On Terminal type: `mongod`

After the process of mongod gets started then you can open new terminal tab to run mongo shell command :

```
mongo --shell
use new_your_database
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "mongo_admin",
     pwd: "mongo_admin",
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
   }
)
```

it should be done successfully....

Comment: Correct way to define roles on mongo db is :

 `"roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase", 
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase", 
            "db" : "admin"
        }, 
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", 
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]`

Answer (score 4):

Below command says, you have created admin user and password.

```
db.getUser("admin")      
{    
        "_id" : "admin.admin",   
        "user" : "admin",    
        "db" : "admin",    
        "roles" : [    
                {    
                        "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",    
                        "db" : "admin"    
                },    
                {    
                        "role" : "clusterAdmin",    
                        "db" : "admin"    
                }    
        ] }    
}
```

Once you create the admin user and password, Mongo will not allow you to do any schema update as normal a admin user which you used to login previously.

Use newly created admin user and password to create new users or do any updates. It should work.

Comment: so it means once created, it won't be removed?

Answer (score 1):

If you're here with the same issue & having a config file to trigger mongod instances- then go ahead and exit from the running process of mongod & in your config file make sure you make security.authorization : disabled, in addition if you've keyFile (i.e; path to a cert file), then comment that spec as well, now start you mongod process using that config file - you should be able to create an user using admin db.

If you work on replica set : Once if you're done with creating a primary node + a user, make sure you initiate & connect to replica set (which again internally connects to primary node),here you can do anything with earlier created user, but when you connect directly to primary node again to execute few commands like **rs.initiate()/rs.status()/show dbs/show users**, you would end-up getting errors like (there are no users authenticated).

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
# keyFile: /opt/mongodb/keyfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for occurring **Not Authorised** error is  because mongo shell was accessed without **username** and **password**.

For executing any command first thing that need to be done is access mongo shell with credentials.

`mongosh -u <user> -p <password>`

(*note that `mongo` for accessing shell does not work anymore it was deprecated*)

After this code can be run without problem:

```
test> db.createUser(
...   {
...     user: "myTester",
...     pwd:  passwordPrompt(),
...     roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" },
...              { role: "read", db: "reporting" } ]
...   }
... )
Enter password
test
****{ ok: 1 }
```